# Python Global Count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in my first year of CS and I'm trying to store a variable that constantly counts 1-6. I want it to cycle through colors 1-6.

I want it to look like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dCnx.png)

My current code just manipulates a string to look like it's scrolling.

```
from time import sleep
from replit import clear
from termcolor import colored

string = input("Input a string to manipulate: ")
clear()

colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'magenta']


# THIS PART DOESNT WORK!!!:
# while True:
#   global y
#   for y in range(6):
#    y += 1

for x in range(23):
  print(colored(string, colors[y]))
  sleep(0.1)

for x in range(19):
  space = " " * x
  print(space+string)
  sleep(0.1)

for x in range(18,0,-1):
  print(" "*x+string)
  sleep(0.1)

print(string)
```

After I input the string, it just stops and doesn't do anything else. If anyone would be able to help out, it would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What happens in the debugger?  Surely you're not asking someone here to run this in a debugger for you?  I can assure you it does not "just stop."

Comment: The part you've commented out is an infinite loop.  What have you done to trace your logic?  Now is a very good time to learn basic debugging, with simple `print` statements and/or a handy debugger.

Comment: Update, I got the first part to start the rainbow, but I'm not sure how I would do it for the next functions where it adds spaces. https://hastebin.com/afovogejub.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from time import sleep
from replit import clear
from termcolor import colored

string = input("Input a string to manipulate: ")
clear()

colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'magenta']

while True:
  for x in range(6):
    print(colored(string, colors[x]))
    sleep(0.1)
```

Use this and build from there.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :D